# How to check if a textbox starts with numeric value

Tags: c#

In Windows forms C#, I want to check if a textbox I made starts with a numeric value, then if it does I want to insert the minus (-) sign at the beginning to change the number to negative, I found a way but it's too time wasting, here's my code:

```cs
if (richTextBox1.Text.StartsWith("1") || richTextBox1.Text.StartsWith("2") #until richTextBox1.Text.StartsWith("9"))
{
    richTextBox1.Text.Insert(0, "-");
}
```

So I was asking, if there's a shorter way to replace that code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if (Char.IsNumber(richTextBox1.Text[0]))...
```

You should also add some checks around it to make sure there's text.

Comment: Is this cultural specific?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ It ["Indicates whether a _Unicode_ character is categorized as a number"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isnumber). Also, check the remarks section for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Using regex:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(richTextBox1.Text, @"^\d"))
```

Matches a digit (0-9) at the start of the string.

Or a direct replace:

```
richTextBox1.Text = Regex.Replace(richTextBox1.Text, @"^\d", "-$&");
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking if the first character of a text is a number can be done in single line, using **Char.IsNumber()** function as follows:

> if ( Char.IsNumber( stringInput, 0) ) {
>
> ```
>  // String input begins with a number
> ```
>
> }

**More information:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isnumber

Answer (score -1):

Many good answer's already here, another alternative is if you want culture support give this a try...

```
 public static bool IsNumber(char character)
 {
    try
    {
       int.Parse(character.ToString(), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
       return true;
    }
       catch (FormatException) { return false; }
 }
```

You can call it like:

```
 if ( IsNumber(richTextBox1.Text[0]))
```